# Transfer data from List to a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a Java code that will extract an unique word from a string containing several sentences and counting the occurences of the word in each sentence.

This is the Java coding used to achieve that. Alternately, you may try it [here](https://repl.it/Bg6D).

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String someText = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

    List<List<String>> sort = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> res = new HashMap<>();

    for (String sentence : someText.split("[.?!]\\s*"))
    {
        sort.add(Arrays.asList(sentence.split("[ ,;:]+"))); //put each sentences in list
    }

    int sentenceCount = sort.size();
    for (List<String> sentence: sort) {
        sentence.stream().forEach(s -> res.put(s, new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(sentenceCount, 0))));
    }
    int index = 0;
    for (List<String> sentence: sort) {
        for (String s : sentence) {
            res.get(s).set(index, res.get(s).get(index) + 1);
        }
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println(res);
  }
}
```

The output from the code is something like this:

```
{standard=[0, 1, 0, 0], but=[0, 0, 1, 0], ..... }
```

which means that the word 'standard' occured none is sentence 1, 1 time in sentence 2, none in sentence 3 & 4.

However, the data is inside a List. How do I convert the data into the form of a 2D matrix so that it will become somewhat like this:

```
    double[][] multi = new double[][]{
          { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
          { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
          { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
          { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
          { 0, 0, 1, 0 } } //data stored in a 2D array named multi
```

Appreciate help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will lose information about which row corresponds to which word. HashMap does not make guarantees about order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop inside a loop should do you.  This code assumes that the rows each have the same number of elements (which they should as there's the same number of possible sentences for each word).  I've added an ArrayList of the keys, so that you can reference them later to know what row index in your matrix corresponds to a given word.

```
ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(res.keySet());
int rowSize = keys.size();
int colSize = res.get(keys.get(0)).size();
double [][] multi = new double[rowSize][colSize];
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowSize; rowIndex++) {
    String key = keys.get(rowIndex);
    List<Integer> row = res.get(key);
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colSize; colIndex++) {
        multi[rowIndex][colIndex] = row.get(colIndex);
    }
}
```

I made the array doubles as that's what is in the question, but it seems ints would be more appropriate.

Apologies for the previous version of this answer; I was looking at the wrong object that you were trying to aggregate.

Comment: thx but it shows some error whenever I run it. https://repl.it/Bg6D/3 Any idea why?

Comment: @Cael sorry about that; I was using the wrong object.  Check out the changes.